# Which setting controls the style of window buttons in Xfce

Tags: xfce, style

I am running Xubuntu 21.04 and my apps are showing two very different styles of window buttons on them. The first is traditional and familiar, while the second looks kind of bizarre. I would like to know what setting controls this. See screenshots.

I switched the theme to greybird, it is the only theme that doesn't produce the bizarre window buttons. But instead, I get giant window buttons on the applications that are affected. They are not flatpak apps. For instance, I get the weird buttons on Gedit and on Xfce Settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug in the second image with the icons appearing twice, albeit larger. A bug report might be in order ... 

Comment: Are you using the default Greybird theme? The erroneous buttons are most likely from applications installed as a snap. The theme of these apps also comes as a snap, and the issue will be there.

Comment: I see the same thing on Gnome 21.04

Comment: I edited the post